# How to call a method from a callback defined in data() in Vue 2.7?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I use a 3rd party component called HelloWorld. The component accepts a prop called closeCallbacks. It is an array of callbacks that are called when the HelloWorld component is closed.

I can not change the way the 3rd party component works.

I implement the template of my component to use HelloWorld component and pass closeCallbacks from the data:

```
<template>
    <HelloWorld :closeCallbacks="closeCallbacks" />
</template>
```

Then, I define the array of callbacks, where one callback item contains a property called action required by HelloWorld component. The action callback is called when HelloWorld is closed:

```
<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
    data() {
        return {
            closeCallbacks: [
                {
                    action: function () {
                        return this.handleCloseCallback();
                    },
                },
            ],

        };
    },
    methods: {
        handleCloseCallback: function () {
        //
        },
    },
});
</script>
```

When the action callback is called, I want to call a method of my component that is called handleCloseCallback (as pictured above).

However in Vue 2.7 I get an error:

```
Property 'handleCloseCallback' does not exist on type '{ name: string; action: (item: any) => void; }'.
```

When I will change handleCloseCallback to an array function:

```
handleCloseCallback: () => {
            //
            },
```

I get another error:

```
Property 'handleCloseCallback' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, {}, {}, {}, false, OptionTypesType<{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}>, ... 5 more ..., {}>'.
```

My question is: how to call a method from a callback defined in data?

Comment: The instance isn't fully constructed in `data`. Although it may work, a computed is likely more suitable for that.

Comment: @EstusFlask it sounds like it would work, but I opted for tao solution because it does not use computed

Comment: It does, but since you use TS, it won't infer closeCallbacks type correctly, needs to be additionally fixed, depending on callback signatures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this fix your issue?

```html
<template>
  <HelloWorld v-if="closeCallbacks.length" :closeCallbacks="closeCallbacks" />
</template>
<script>
export default defineComponent({
  data: () => ({
    closeCallbacks: []
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.closeCallbacks = [{ action: this.handleCloseCallback }]
  },
  methods: {
    handleCloseCallback() {}
  }
})
<script>
```

Point being: `this.handleCloseCallback` is defined on `mounted`, but it's not yet defined at the time `data` is parsed.
Note I used a `v-if` to defer rendering of the components until `closeCallbacks` is populated, to avoid the initial rendering of the component with an empty `closeCallbacks`.

---

I believe this is what Estus was suggesting. Not only it should also work, but I find it much cleaner:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  computed: {
    closeCallbacks() {
      return [{ action: this.handleCloseCallback }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleCloseCallback() {}
  }
})
```

Comment: I tend to agree with @EstusFlask. A `computed` would be much cleaner here. Updated the answer with an example. Besides, you no longer need to defer component rendering. The only scenario in which you should keep the array in `data` is if you might want to modify it after component has mounted.